# cant use sleep() in embedded c for stm32

Tags: c, sleep, stm32

I try to learn embedded c for a stm32-microcontorller. I try to wirte a easy blink program, where i use the sleep()-function.

code:

```c
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <unistd.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  while (1)
  { 
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port,LD2_Pin);
    sleep(1);  // this line throws a error, when compiling
  }
}
```

the compiler gives me following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.4.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled2.elf.dir/Src/main.c.obj: in function `main':
/home/heinrich/CLionProjects/untitled2/Src/main.c:106: undefined reference to `sleep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled2.elf.dir/build.make:391: untitled2.elf] Fehler 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/untitled2.elf.dir/all] Fehler 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/untitled2.elf.dir/rule] Fehler 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: untitled2.elf] Fehler 2
```

I think, the problem is a not-installed libary, but i installed everything in the fedora-repos for arm-gcc

OS: Fedora 30
IDE: CLion
Toolchain: Arm-gcc-none-eabi

Comment: What flags are used for ld?

Comment: there is already `HAL_Delay()` function, you can use it instead of `sleep()` this is not fix for your problem just an alternative way ... Also, you should init `CLK` for `GPIO` and `GPIO` itself.

Comment: GPIO and CLK are initialized, but i left it out, bc not relevant

Comment: `sleep` is not standard but Linux-specific. Your STM32 is not a Linux PC.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question, you need to set data direction registers and possibly port mapping somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use POSIX functions on bare-metal target with arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler. There is no operating system. There is no `sleep()`, `gettimeofday()`, `clock_gettime()`, `getpid()`, `fork()`, `stat()`, `open()`, `pthread_create()` and many, many, many others C and posix and *unix specific functions. The declarations of these functions can be found in the standard headers, but linker will just give up with `undefined reference` error. You have to implement them yourself.

Your compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc by default uses [newlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newlib) implementation of C standard library. It comes with an implementation of most basic and not operating system aware functions, like `snprintf` and `mktime`. For functions like `printf` or `putc` the callback `_write()` or `_write_r()` should be implemented for them to work. For `malloc()` to work you have to provide `sbrk()`. For most other functions, you have to implement them yourself.

The commonly used `-specs=nosys.specs` compiler option just specifies to use a "default" no-system implementation of some functions like `fseek()` or `write()` or `sbrk()`. Most of these functions just return `-1` and set errno to `ENOSYS`, but are there, so that you can compile your program. The implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/littlekernel/newlib/tree/master/libgloss/libnosys).

If you happen to use stm32 hal library, you can initialize your systick interrupt for 1 ms and use the standard in stm32 world `HAL_Delay()` function and provide your own implementation of `sleep()`:

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds) {
   HAL_Delay(seconds * 1000);
   return 0;
}
```

The other way round is to use an operating system on your device that provides an implementation of these functions. For example there is [RIOT OS](https://riot-os.org/) that aims at providing POSIX compatibility and already provides many calls.

Answer (score 2):

Micro-controller may not have standard library included, so in this case you must roll your own missing functions. For example sleep could be implemented like this:

```
void my_sleep(int secs) {
  #define STEPS_PER_SEC 650000000
  unsigned int i,s;
  for (s=0; s < secs; s++) {
    for (i=0; i < STEPS_PER_SEC; i++) {
       // skip CPU cycle or any other statement(s) for making loop 
       // untouched by C compiler code optimizations
       asm("nop");
    }
  }
}

int main() {
   my_sleep(1);
}
```

Btw constant `STEPS_PER_SEC` should be adjusted empirically according to your controller CPU specs and your compilation mode (optimizations On / Off, etc.).

Comment: This will not work with optimizations [enabled](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/mjhjHq)

Comment: See my edit - I've added `asm("nop");` for loop(s) not being factored out by compiler optimizations. If NOP is factored out in STM32 microcontroller too - then something else may be added instead of nop, dependent on the platform / cpu.

Comment: Possibly `asm volatile("nop");` could be used? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449141/the-difference-between-asm-asm-volatile-and-clobbering-memory