Using std::this_thread::sleep_for on Raspberry Pi Pico
when I add this line of code to my project
std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);

I get this linker error
./build/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++/src/c++11/../../../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:228: undefined reference to `usleep'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./build/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++/src/c++11/../../../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:238: undefined reference to `sleep'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./build/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++/src/c++11/../../../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:238: undefined reference to `sleep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've tried fixing this error by adding...
void usleep(uint64_t microseconds) {
    sleep_us(microseconds);
}

but I'm not sure if I have the signature right or if it's even possible(or appropriate) to fix the problem with this approach. Does anyone know how to correct this? Or am I just stuck switching all of my std::this_thread::sleep_for's to sleep_us's to get my code working on the pico?
EDIT: I was able to find this code, it fixes the problem
extern "C" {
int usleep(useconds_t microseconds) {
    sleep_us(microseconds);
    return 0;
}
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds) {
    sleep_ms(seconds * 1000);
    return 0;
}
}

EDIT: adding full build output
~/C/picopiproject $ cmake --fresh -G Ninja && ninja
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


PICO_SDK_PATH is /home/david/C/pico-sdk
Defaulting PICO_PLATFORM to rp2040 since not specified.
Defaulting PICO platform compiler to pico_arm_gcc since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
PICO compiler is pico_arm_gcc
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
Build type is Release
Defaulting PICO target board to pico since not specified.
Using board configuration from /home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.11.2") found components: Interpreter
TinyUSB available at /home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
BTstack available at /home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/btstack
cyw43-driver available at /home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
Pico W Bluetooth build support available.
lwIP available at /home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
mbedtls available at /home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/david/C/picopiproject
[1/76] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
ninja: no work to do.
[2/76] Performing build step for 'PioasmBuild'
ninja: no work to do.
[76/76] Linking CXX executable prog.elf
FAILED: prog.elf
: && /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wl,--build-id=none --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,--wrap=sprintf -Wl,--wrap=snprintf -Wl,--wrap=vsnprintf -Wl,--wrap=__clzsi2 -Wl,--wrap=__clzdi2 -Wl,--wrap=__ctzsi2 -Wl,--wrap=__ctzdi2 -Wl,--wrap=__popcountsi2 -Wl,--wrap=__popcountdi2 -Wl,--wrap=__clz -Wl,--wrap=__clzl -Wl,--wrap=__clzll -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_idiv -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_idivmod -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_ldivmod -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_uidiv -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_uidivmod -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_uldivmod -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dadd -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_ddiv -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dmul -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_drsub -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dsub -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_cdcmpeq -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_cdrcmple -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_cdcmple -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dcmpeq -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dcmplt -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dcmple -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dcmpge -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dcmpgt -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_dcmpun -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_i2d -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_l2d -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_ui2d -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_ul2d -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_d2iz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_d2lz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_d2uiz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_d2ulz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_d2f -Wl,--wrap=sqrt -Wl,--wrap=cos -Wl,--wrap=sin -Wl,--wrap=tan -Wl,--wrap=atan2 -Wl,--wrap=exp -Wl,--wrap=log -Wl,--wrap=ldexp -Wl,--wrap=copysign -Wl,--wrap=trunc -Wl,--wrap=floor -Wl,--wrap=ceil -Wl,--wrap=round -Wl,--wrap=sincos -Wl,--wrap=asin -Wl,--wrap=acos -Wl,--wrap=atan -Wl,--wrap=sinh -Wl,--wrap=cosh -Wl,--wrap=tanh -Wl,--wrap=asinh -Wl,--wrap=acosh -Wl,--wrap=atanh -Wl,--wrap=exp2 -Wl,--wrap=log2 -Wl,--wrap=exp10 -Wl,--wrap=log10 -Wl,--wrap=pow -Wl,--wrap=powint -Wl,--wrap=hypot -Wl,--wrap=cbrt -Wl,--wrap=fmod -Wl,--wrap=drem -Wl,--wrap=remainder -Wl,--wrap=remquo -Wl,--wrap=expm1 -Wl,--wrap=log1p -Wl,--wrap=fma -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_lmul -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fadd -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fdiv -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fmul -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_frsub -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fsub -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_cfcmpeq -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_cfrcmple -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_cfcmple -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fcmpeq -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fcmplt -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fcmple -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fcmpge -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fcmpgt -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_fcmpun -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_i2f -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_l2f -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_ui2f -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_ul2f -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_f2iz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_f2lz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_f2uiz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_f2ulz -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_f2d -Wl,--wrap=sqrtf -Wl,--wrap=cosf -Wl,--wrap=sinf -Wl,--wrap=tanf -Wl,--wrap=atan2f -Wl,--wrap=expf -Wl,--wrap=logf -Wl,--wrap=ldexpf -Wl,--wrap=copysignf -Wl,--wrap=truncf -Wl,--wrap=floorf -Wl,--wrap=ceilf -Wl,--wrap=roundf -Wl,--wrap=sincosf -Wl,--wrap=asinf -Wl,--wrap=acosf -Wl,--wrap=atanf -Wl,--wrap=sinhf -Wl,--wrap=coshf -Wl,--wrap=tanhf -Wl,--wrap=asinhf -Wl,--wrap=acoshf -Wl,--wrap=atanhf -Wl,--wrap=exp2f -Wl,--wrap=log2f -Wl,--wrap=exp10f -Wl,--wrap=log10f -Wl,--wrap=powf -Wl,--wrap=powintf -Wl,--wrap=hypotf -Wl,--wrap=cbrtf -Wl,--wrap=fmodf -Wl,--wrap=dremf -Wl,--wrap=remainderf -Wl,--wrap=remquof -Wl,--wrap=expm1f -Wl,--wrap=log1pf -Wl,--wrap=fmaf -Wl,--wrap=malloc -Wl,--wrap=calloc -Wl,--wrap=realloc -Wl,--wrap=free -Wl,--wrap=memcpy -Wl,--wrap=memset -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_memcpy -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_memset -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_memcpy4 -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_memset4 -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_memcpy8 -Wl,--wrap=__aeabi_memset8 -Wl,-Map=prog.elf.map -Wl,--script=/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/memmap_default.ld -Wl,-z,max-page-size=4096 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-warn-rwx-segments -Wl,--wrap=printf -Wl,--wrap=vprintf -Wl,--wrap=puts -Wl,--wrap=putchar -Wl,--wrap=getchar CMakeFiles/prog.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdlib/stdlib.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_gpio/gpio.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_platform/platform.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_claim/claim.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_sync/sync.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_irq/irq.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_irq/irq_handler_chain.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/sem.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/lock_core.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/mutex.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/critical_section.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_time/time.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_time/timeout_helper.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_timer/timer.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/datetime.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/pheap.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/queue.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_uart/uart.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_clocks/clocks.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_pll/pll.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_vreg/vreg.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_watchdog/watchdog.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_xosc/xosc.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_divider/divider.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_runtime/runtime.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_printf/printf.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bit_ops/bit_ops_aeabi.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bootrom/bootrom.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_divider/divider.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_aeabi.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_init_rom.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_math.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_v1_rom_shim.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_int64_ops/pico_int64_ops_aeabi.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_aeabi.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_init_rom.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_math.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_v1_rom_shim.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_malloc/pico_malloc.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_mem_ops/mem_ops_aeabi.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/crt0.S.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/new_delete.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/binary_info.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio/stdio.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/reset_interface.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb_descriptors.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_unique_id/unique_id.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_flash/flash.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040/dcd_rp2040.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040/rp2040_usb.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/device/usbd.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/device/usbd_control.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/audio/audio_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/cdc/cdc_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/dfu/dfu_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/dfu/dfu_rt_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/hid/hid_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/midi/midi_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/msc/msc_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/net/ecm_rndis_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/net/ncm_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/usbtmc/usbtmc_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/vendor/vendor_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/video/video_device.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/tusb.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/common/tusb_fifo.c.obj CMakeFiles/prog.dir/home/david/C/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_fix/rp2040_usb_device_enumeration/rp2040_usb_device_enumeration.c.obj -o prog.elf  pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/bs2_default_padded_checksummed.S && cd /home/david/C/picopiproject && /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Oihex /home/david/C/picopiproject/prog.elf prog.hex && cd /home/david/C/picopiproject && /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Obinary /home/david/C/picopiproject/prog.elf prog.bin && cd /home/david/C/picopiproject && /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -h /home/david/C/picopiproject/prog.elf > prog.dis && /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d /home/david/C/picopiproject/prog.elf >> prog.dis && cd /home/david/C/picopiproject && /home/david/C/picopiproject/elf2uf2/elf2uf2 /home/david/C/picopiproject/prog.elf prog.uf2
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++.a(thread.o): in function `std::this_thread::__sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1ll> >, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> >)':
./build/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++/src/c++11/../../../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:228: undefined reference to `usleep'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./build/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++/src/c++11/../../../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:238: undefined reference to `sleep'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./build/thumb/v6-m/nofp/libstdc++/src/c++11/../../../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:238: undefined reference to `sleep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


These signatures must be defined in a header file, which is (possible indirectly) included by thread.cc. (Otherwise the compiler would complain about it)

i believe it's only the linker that is complaining

What compiler command line are you using?

@AlanBirtles added the full build output

Judging by "arm-none-eabi", sounds like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592338/4165552

Please don't edit solutions into your question, if you've solved your own problem you can post an answer. Please also don't label your edits with Edit: there's an edit history for that

@pptaszni that does explain why the functions arent there but doesn't explain why sleep_for would even use them. shouldn't the Pico SDK include working implementations of sleep_for and such?

Try linking to the pthread library:  -lpthread.
