# Please explain me this C snippet

Tags: c, gcc

I have found this little piece of C gem in the gcc torture tests suite, and more or less I understand it, except the lines marked with my comments ...

```
void __attribute__((noinline,noclone))
foo(int *p, float *q) { __asm__ volatile ("" : : : "memory"); } /// ??? 1

int main()
{
  if (sizeof (int) == sizeof (float))
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      int *p;
      /* Prevent i and f from being rewritten into SSA form. */
      foo (&i, &f);
      i = 0;
      f = 1.0;
      p = (int *)&f;
      __builtin_memcpy (&i, p, 4);     /// ??? 2
      if (*(float *)&i != 1.0)
        __builtin_abort ();
    }
  return 0;
}
```

So, question number 1:

What is this `__asm__ volatile ("" : : : "memory");` ? Didn't see this syntax till now ...

Question number 2:

Since `__builtin_memcpy` feels to me as being a function where is this defined? The full source code compiles and runs as it is, (without any extra includes and libraries) so I'm dazed ... Is there a set of `__builtin***` functions which are available via gcc, without using any library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__asm__ volatile` is a way to write your own inline asm code, and the `volatile` bit means that gcc can't delete it. [Check this answer for links & details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955162/why-does-adding-assembly-comments-cause-such-radical-change-in-generated-code).
The function, then is written in asm, and the use of the (GCC specific attribute) `noinline` means that this code won't be inlined by the compiler. In case you're wondering.

`__builtin_memcpy` is a GCC built-in (obviously) version of the `memcpy` function. Sometimes, though, the regular, standard `memcpy` function will be used, or the other way around (`memcpy` can be *"optimized"* by gcc, and result in a `__builtin_memcpy` call).
The use of this is debatable, and writing code that targets specific compiler extensions isn't really a great idea, but given that this code is part of the gcc torture test suite, it makes sense to use the `__buitlin*`functions explicitly, as in some cases, [they could well perform worse than the standard functions](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2013-January/039227.html)

Answer (score 3):

> What is this **asm** volatile ("" : : : "memory"); ?

This baisically means that the assembly code will be executed where you expect it to execute. Compiler is informed not to reorder instructions around it.

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering):

> These barriers prevent a compiler from reordering instructions, they
>   do not prevent reordering by CPU.

You may also find the details about this syntax **[Volatile ...?](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4).**

Comment: for that syntax question, basicly it is inline assembler in C: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s4 , this one having the impact you stated