# How to associate assembly code to exact line in C program?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb

Here is an example found via an assembly website. This is the C code:

```
 int main()
 {
     int a = 5;
     int b = a + 6;
     return 0;
 }
```

Here is the associated assembly code:

```
    (gdb) disassemble
    Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x0000000100000f50 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
    0x0000000100000f51 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
    0x0000000100000f54 <main+4>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x0000000100000f59 <main+9>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    0x0000000100000f60 <main+16>:   movl   $0x5,-0x8(%rbp)
    0x0000000100000f67 <main+23>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%ecx
    0x0000000100000f6a <main+26>:   add    $0x6,%ecx
    0x0000000100000f70 <main+32>:   mov    %ecx,-0xc(%rbp)
    0x0000000100000f73 <main+35>:   pop    %rbp
    0x0000000100000f74 <main+36>:   retq   
    End of assembler dump.
```

I can safely assume that this line of assembly code:

```
  0x0000000100000f6a <main+26>:   add    $0x6,%ecx
```

correlates to this line of C:

```
     int b = a + 6;
```

But is there a way to extract which lines of assembly are associated to the specific line of C code?
In this small sample it's not too difficult, but in larger programs and when debugging a larger amount of code it gets a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If using GCC, there is an option to output annotated assembly with comments mapping it to the C-code. I'm sure clang offers a similar solution.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137479/1870232)

Comment: Yes.  Compile with debug symbols and then look at it in the debugger again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc)

Comment: compile with the -ggdb3 option.  Then all the line number, etc information is available in the object file.

Answer (score 7):

> But is there a way to extract which lines of assembly are associated to the specific line of C code?

Yes, in principle - your compiler can probably do it (GCC option `-fverbose-asm`, for example). Alternatively, `objdump -lSd` or similar will disassemble a program or object file with source and line number annotations where available.

In general though, for a large optimized program, this can be very hard to follow.

Even with perfect annotation, you'll see the same source line mentioned multiple times as expressions and statements are split up, interleaved and reordered, and some instructions associated with multiple source expressions.

In this case, you just need to think about the relationship between your source and the assembly, but it takes some effort.

Comment: Yes, and it gets very worse (for you human) as soon as you turn optimizations on.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best tools I've found for this is Matthew Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org).

It features multiple compiler toolchains, auto-recompiles, and it immediately shows the assembly output with colored lines to show the corresponding line of source code.

Comment: Neat looking tool.

Comment: And in any case it's open source so you can probably find how he does it

Comment: the tool is great, and you can support its development with Patreon.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to compile the program keeping inside its object file informations about the source code either via `gdwarf` or `g` flag or both.  Next, if you want to debug it is important for the compiler to avoid optimizations, otherwise it is difficult to see a correspondence code<>assembly.

```
gcc -gdwarf -g3 -O0 prog.c -o out
```

Next, tell the disassembler to output the source code. The `source` flag involves the `disassemble` flag.

```
objdump --source out
```

Answer (score 0):

@Useless is very right. Anyways, a trick to know where C has arrived in the machine code is to inject markers in it; for instance,

```
#define ASM_MARK do { asm __volatile__("nop; nop; nop;\n\t" :::); } while (0);

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    ASM_MARK;
       int b = a + 6;
    ASM_MARK;
    return 0;
}
```

You will see:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
        nop; nop; nop;

        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        addl    $6, %eax
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
        nop; nop; nop;

        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

You need to use the `__volatile__` keyword or equivalent in order to tell the compiler not to interfere and this is often compiler-specific (notice the `__`), as C does not 
provide this kind of syntax.

Comment: This is very Gnu compiler-specific, and may also interfere with the optimizer, so while it is a trick to be aware of, it is also one to wield with caution. There are much better ways.

Comment: @CodyGray: That is a good point. I've hinted even further the fact that nothing is touched or produced, so there will be very likely no data saving instructions around the asm at all.

Comment: I understand what you are thinking, and it does *seem* that inserting some `NOP`s with no input/output operands would have no effect. But, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955162/why-does-adding-assembly-comments-cause-such-radical-change-in-generated-code) for a demonstration of how the insertion of a *comment* using inline assembly can disrupt vectorization of code.